# Low pass Linear Filter in python

Tags: python, pandas, filter, scipy, time-series

I have red a lot about filtering time series but I really have difficulties to understand properly the scipy `scipy.signal.filtfilt`.

In particular its parameters a and b.
For example how I should reproduce the following filter?
Even with others libs if is easier.

[image]

Can anyone help me? I give you a starting point:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100
rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='min', periods=N)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N, 1), index=rng)
```

Answer (score 2):

You say your plot shows a low-pass linear filter.  I assume the plot shows the coefficients of a [FIR filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response).  If so, you can pass those coefficients as the `b` argument of [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) (or `scipy.signal.filtfilt`, but using `filtfilt` with a FIR filter is probably not what you want).  Set the `a` parameter to 1.

You could also apply the filter to a signal with a convolution function, such as `numpy.convolve`, `scipy.signal.convolve` or `scipy.ndimage.convolve1d`.  Take a look at the article [Applying a FIR Filter](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ApplyFIRFilter.html) (but note that the performance results shown there are not up to date--both NumPy and SciPy continue to develop, and the relative performance of the different methods discussed there can change between versions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you clarify better with an example?